# Under what circumstances is $P(X ≥ t) = P(X^2 ≥ t^2 )$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I saw this on http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf, proof for Chebyshev’s inequality. Could someone explain this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative,

then we have $a \ge b$ if and only if $a^2 \ge b^2$ as $x^2$ is a mononotinically increasing function for nonnegative numbers.

$t$ is assumed to be positive in that theorem.